# How do I properly use the "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256" algorithm?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, password-encryption

I'm doing some Java encryption, and cannot figure out a way to properly use the the PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256 algorithm.

Encryption seems to work fine, but I am unable to properly initialize a decryption cipher.

Below is a short program that demonstrates the issue.
In particular, see the "PROBLEM" comment.

Note: I have seen [this very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992413), and I can get things to work using that scheme, but I'm curious to know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

public final class CryptQuestion {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256";
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 1000; // Aside: not sure what is a good number, here.

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String message = "This is the secret message... BOO!";
        System.out.println("Original : " + message);
        final byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

        final String password = "some password";
        final byte[] salt = "would be random".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

        // Create the Key
        final SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        final PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATIONS);
        SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        // Build the encryption cipher.
        final Cipher cipherEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        // Encrypt!
        final byte[] ciphertext = cipherEncrypt.doFinal(messageBytes);
        final byte[] iv = cipherEncrypt.getIV();

        // Now for decryption... The receiving end will have as input:
        // * ciphertext
        // * IV
        // * password
        // * salt

        // We just re-use 'key' from above, since it will be identical.

        final PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);
        final IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // Build the decryption cipher.
        final Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // PROBLEM: If I pass "ivParamSpec", I get "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong parameter type: PBE expected"
        // Whereas if I pass pbeParamSpec, I get "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Missing parameter type: IV expected"
        // What to do?
        cipherDecrypt.init(
                Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                key,
                ivParamSpec
                //pbeParamSpec
                );

        final String decrypted = new String(
                cipherDecrypt.doFinal(ciphertext),
                StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decrypted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this code requires Java 8 with the unlimited-strength policy files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// PROBLEM: If I pass "ivParamSpec", I get "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong parameter type: PBE expected"
// Whereas if I pass pbeParamSpec, I get "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Missing parameter type: IV expected"
// What to do?
cipherDecrypt.init(
    Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
    key,
    ivParamSpec
    //pbeParamSpec
    );
```

Use the `AlgorithmParameters` from the encrypting `Cipher`:

```
cipherDecrypt.init(
    Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
    key,
    cipherEncrypt.getParameters()
    );
```

If you want a cleaner way that doesn't involve `cipherEncrypt` at the decrypting site, save the algorithm parameters as a byte and transmit them along with the key data:

```
byte[]  algorithmParametersEncoded = cipherEncrypt.getParameters().getEncoded();
```

and reconstruct them at the decrypting site thus:

```
AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
algorithmParameters.init(algorithmParametersEncoded);
```

and use `algorithmParameters` as the `parameters` argument for `Cipher.init()` above.

Comment: And as a side question: the encoded algorithm params are ... implementation specific, I take it? I mean, if I wanted to encrypt in Python but decrypt in Java (or vice-versa), is there any good way to replicate whatever "algorithmParametersEncoded" represents?

Comment: @jwd Sorry, I pass. There is reference in the Javadoc to them being encoded in ASN.1, which indicates language-independence, but whether you can encode or decode them in Python is unknown to me.

Comment: Yeah, upon further research, it does seem to be ASN.1 encoded (DER, specifically). It can be parsed with pyasn1, for instance. I don't know how strongly this format is guaranteed by Java, though.

Comment: @jwd If the Javadoc says ASN.1 you can rely on it not changing to something else.

Comment: The javadoc merely says "The primary decoding format for parameters is ASN.1, if an ASN.1 specification for this type of parameters exists." It murky as to whether one can be confident that such an encoding exists for any particular params. In my case I got lucky, though (:

Answer (score 2):

For those who jumps here from google. There is another way to specify IV for PBEwithHmacSHA512AndAES_256 cipher in java. IvParameterSpec can be added to PBEParameterSpec in constructor like this:

```
byte[] iv = ...;
byte[] salt = ...;
int iterations = 200000;

IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
PBEParameterSpec pbeSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations, ivSpec);
```

Then such pbeSpec can be used to initialize the cipher:

```
cipher.init(
    Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
    key,
    pbeSpec
);
```

Anyway the accepted answer provides a much cleaner solution - to serialize all cipher parameters at once with cipherEncrypt.getParameters().getEncoded(). The resulting byte array includes IV, salt and iteration count at once. It is completely ok to pass this data next to ciphered message at least for PBEwithHmacSHA512AndAES_256 algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I've enhanced the StandardPBEByteEncryptor from teh jasyptto support the "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256" algorithm. see code [here](https://github.com/mhisoft/common-utils/blob/bdd9d76db5ccd64472fd8ba2ed4f1cdd399915b5/src/main/java/org/mhisoft/common/util/security/StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java)

See the unit test here [PBEEncryptorTest](https://github.com/mhisoft/common-utils/blob/bdd9d76db5ccd64472fd8ba2ed4f1cdd399915b5/src/test/java/org/mhisoft/common/util/PBEEncryptorTest.java)