# Cannot decrypt a file that I encrypted using PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, passwords

So I have been stuck for ages and am having trouble decrypting a file that I encrypted using PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128.

The encryption works fine, but when trying to decrypt it, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong parameter type: PBE expected

The error is happening at this line:

```
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, ivSpec);
```

Here is the encryption code I used:

```
// Create PBE parameter set
pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, COUNT);
pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(get_SHA_1_SecurePassword(password, SALT).toCharArray());
keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");

SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
// PRINT HASH OF PW  
System.out.println(get_SHA_1_SecurePassword(password, SALT).toCharArray());

// Create PBE Cipher and initialise PBE Cipher with key and parameters
Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

// Get bytes of input file
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
inputStream.read(inputBytes);

// Encrypt and get bytes of encrypted file
byte[] iv = pbeCipher.getIV();
byte[] outputBytes = pbeCipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

String fileName = inputFile.getName();
File outputFile = new File(fileName + ".enc");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

// store first 16 bytes in the file as the IV
outputStream.write(iv);

// store the rest of the encrypted file
outputStream.write(outputBytes);
inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();

return outputFile;
```

Here is the decryption I am trying to get working:

```
// Create PBE parameter set
pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, COUNT);
pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(hashedReadPasswords[index].toCharArray());
keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");

SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

// Create PBE Cipher
Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");

// Get bytes of encrypted file
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int)encryptedFile.length()];
inputStream.read(inputBytes);

// Get IV
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
{
  iv[i] = inputBytes[i];
}

// Get encrypted data
byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[inputBytes.length-16];
int y=0;
for(int i=16; i<inputBytes.length; i++)
{
  cipherBytes[y] = inputBytes[i];
  y++;
}

// Initialise PBE Cipher with key and parameters
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, ivSpec);

// decrypt and get bytes of plain text file
byte[] outputBytes = pbeCipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);

File outputFile = new File("decrypted_BS13");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

// store the rest of the decrypted file
outputStream.write(outputBytes);
inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();

return outputFile;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, no matter what I find online - it's not helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Please see [this blog](http://javapapers.com/java/java-file-encryption-decryption-using-password-based-encryption-pbe/) for example PBE encryption and decryption code (although don't use the same ciphers that the blog is using because they are insecure!) that works.

You have a few problems here.

This is definitely wrong, although it is not causing the problem you are describing:

```
pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(hashedReadPasswords[index].toCharArray());
```

You need to provide the same password as was used to encrypt it.  You cannot put in a hashed password to decrypt.  So you need to pass in a similar pbeKeySpec as you used for encrypt.

PBE means "password based encryption".  It is an algorithm for turning a password into an encryption key, in a secure way.  This means that the key you decrypt with needs to be the same as the key you encrypt with, and derived the same way.

Comment: You're right I know that you shouldn't use the actual hash to encrypt, but I was trying to decrypt using the same exact hash (i used the same salt). Is there a way to get this working without using external libraries? I am only supposed to use the standard cryptography library that comes with java

Comment: @chozenn300 I think the blog I referenced is using only Java, no external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved here: [How do I properly use the "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256" algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215274/how-do-i-properly-use-the-pbewithhmacsha512andaes-256-algorithm#answer-29224454)

Because the algorithm uses **AES** to cipher, you need the used **IV** to decipher. Although, you also need the PBE parameters (**The error you are getting**), so, to get the *IvParameterSpec*  and *PBEParameterSpec*  has one variable, you call `pbeCipher.getParameters()` that returns a *AlgorithmParameters* instance containing the *IvParameterSpec* and *PBEParameterSpec* used on the cipher.
**Warning: you must call the method after the init**

### Cipher

```
Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
AlgorithmParameters params = pbeCipher.getParameters();
```

### Decipher

```
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, params);
```